# How to capture strings between two words/characters

Tags: notepad++, regex, oracle-database, toad

How to capture strings between two words/characters either or both words have multiple occurrences but I want the words both from the first column.

```
1. A-Hi hello C-0987654321 
2. B-Zzzzzzzzzzzz D-Hi
3. C-I want to go to Europe C- Nexy year D-I wish so 
4. D-Are
5. E-You
6. F-Test
7. G-Test
8. H-Test
9. I-Test
10.J-Test
```

Desired Capture: `C-I want to go to Europe    C- Nexy year D-I wish so`

I used regex `\C-.+\D-` but it captures C-0987654321 B-Zzzzzzzzzzzz

I want to capture between lines `3.C-` and `4.D-`(all from first column) which is “ C-I want to go to Europe C- Nexy year D-I wish so”

Comment: So what are the columns though, is `<#>.` column 1 and then the rest after that `<Column2>`? What does the query you used with the SQL including the regex look like? Or will a solution parsing these results as a string or from text file also work? If you want SQL logic help, it might be best to show example of that including the regex in the select statement.

Comment: The numbering represents lines, it’s just like saying line 1 to 10. I want to capture the strings between C- from line#3 first col and D- from line#4 first col. The value is “ C-I want to go to Europe C- Nexy year D-I wish so”. Supposed the entire data is in one file (BLOB) and in textfile like in notedpad++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using Notepad++

---

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `C-.+D-.+`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Find Next</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
C-      # literally C and hyphen
.+      # 1 or more any character but newline
D-      # literally D and hyphen
.+      # 1 or more any character but newline
```

**Screenshot:**

[image]

Comment: That’s exactly what I want @Toto, let me translate it in toad sql query tomorrow and let you know if it works in sql query…Thank you.

Comment: @MitchelAraw: You're welcome, glad it helps. I don't know the regex flavour in toad sql but if it will work if it is PCRE.

Comment: Just tried @Toto it works with “ \C-.+\D-.+ “.  Thank you. really appreciate it.

Comment: @MitchelAraw: Feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Hi @Toto, done. Thank you so much.

Comment: Hi @Toto I have another question but related to my previous one so I don’t need to raise a new question, what’s the regex if I’m going to capture the second occurrence from the multiple occurrences example the Test has 5 occurrences but I want to capture the second only from line 7. Thanks.

Comment: @MitchelAraw: It's too complex to answer in comment. You should ask a new question with sample text and expected result.

Comment: Sure. Thank you.